# What is the Correct way to enable JQuery Code Hinting and Completion in Aptana Studio 3?

Tags: jquery, aptana, aptana3, codehighlighter, code-hinting

Hey Guys I am in the process of learning JQuery and I started using Aptana a couple days ago because I read that is was a great IDE.

I am having trouble enabling the JQuery code hinting feature though.
I have read several articles about how to enable this feature I have done them and still nothing.

Here is what I have done so far:

1. Clicked Command
2. Bundle Development
3. Install Bundle
4. Selected the JQuery Bundle

after I select the JQuery bundle Aptana downloaded the files from Github,

1. I restarted Aptana
2. I created a new WEB PROJECT
3. Downloaded and Linked to the JQuery file

and still NO code hints or support.
Please help as code hinting is vital in my learning process of these languages, thats how I learnt PHP.

Thanks.

EDIT: Never mind I found a another article which helped. heres [the link](https://aptanastudio.tenderapp.com/discussions/problems/2006-studio-3-jquery-support-is-lacking) if anyone having trouble needs it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try this:

Windows >> Pereferneces >> Aptana Studio > Editors > PHP > Libraries (or only searchfield: libraries), and set a "New User-Library" with eclipse.

So the magic may be to activate the libraries for general use. Otherwise you can only activate the libraries for each Project, you need it for.

Here you can also add PEAR, ZEND-Framework and other libraries